# -beginner- trouble with multiple users and variables

Tags: node.js, variables

I'm trying to build a module that handle a form like a powerpoint (slide by slide) I described my form in a Json file.

When a user connects I read the json and serve him the first question. When the user click on the `next` button I iterate on my counter and serve him the second question.

*For one user it works great.*

But I came to realize that when two user are connected they share the same counter.

This is a problem.

In order to fix this issue :
I could handle an `array` with `session ID` to identify each user. But I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do so.

Obviously I'm a beginner with node.js

What I do in app.js

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var form = require('./controllers/form');
    form.init();

    socket.on('next', function(data) {
        socket.emit('next', form.next());
    });
});
```

A part of my form.js for you to better understand my problem :

```
var formController = {
    'form': [],
    'lookup_part_iterator': 0,
    'lookup_diapo': {},
    'lookup_diapo_iterator': 0,
    'init': function() {//stuff},
    'next': function() {//stuff},
    'end': function() {//stuff},
    'get_next_slide': function() {//stuff},
    'iterate_slide': function() {//stuff},
    'iterate_part': function() {//stuff},

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do it but I'm not satisfied please if someone know a better way to do this explain it.
In app.js :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

var form = require('./controlers/form');
form.init();
var form_copy = _.extend({},form);
    socket.set( socket.id, form_copy, function() {
    console.log("form setted");
    socket.on('next', function(data) {
        console.log("next");
        socket.get( socket.id,function(error,form_socket){
            //I will handle the error ty Tim
            console.log("form getted"+error);
             console.log(form_socket);
            socket.emit('next', form_socket.next());
        });

    });
});


});
```

@Tim Brown : in my case socket.set alone is not working because it's passing a reference so I end up dealing with the same issue.

My workaround is to make a copy of the form object before passing it to socket.set.
But as I said I'm not satisfied even thow it's working.
Maybe It's the best way tell me what you think in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use `socket.set(key, value, cb)` and `socket.get(key, function(err, value){...})`

UPDATE: Added the whole thing in context.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var form = require('./controllers/form');
    form.init();
    socket.set("form", form)

    socket.on('next', function() {
        socket.get('form', function(err, form) {
            // HANDLE THE ERR, usually just something like if(err){ return }
            socket.emit('next', form.next());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm a beginner ! like really. it would help me a lot if you put your snippet in my code context.

Comment: @user2707404 its really basics , try `socket.io` documentation https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki , copy/paste won't help you reach your goal.

Comment: @Phoenix ok I get your point but if I'm asking it's because I need help I already checked the wiki and I didn't find what I'm asking here. So in order to help me you can either explain me what I missed in the wiki and even why. Or if you don't have time you can paste me some code. What you did here is not helping at all nor me or anyone.

Comment: Edited to take my best guess at it in your context, as I don't have any idea what the form object is doing.  Don't be afraid to try stuff out yourself first; there isn't a limit on code failures and you'd learn faster by doing rather than copying.

Comment: Thank you Tim brown. I tried that already. unfortunatly I was'nt able to answer at my own question (not enough points) within 8 hours.